# How do I create a databricks table from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a pandas dataframe that I've created. This prints out fine, however I need to manipulate this in SQL.

I've run the following:

```
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

spark_df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("temp.testa")

pd_df = spark.sql('select * from temp.testa').toPandas()
```

But get an error:

```
AnalysisException: Database 'temp' not found;
```

Obviously I have not created a database, but not sure how to do this.

Can anyone advise how I might go about achieving what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message clearly says "`AnalysisException: Database 'temp' not found;`" database temp is not found. Once the database is created you can run the query without any issue.

To create a database, you can use the below command:

To create a database in SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE <database-name>
```

[image]

Reference: [Azure Databricks - SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/)